# Two Bibliographies In One Page

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, multibib

I'm using the `multibib` package and the documentclass `report` with `pdflatex`.

This is my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{multibib}
        \newcites{readinglist}{Reading List}
        \newcites{resources}{Resources}
\begin{document}
    \bibliographystylereadinglist{plain}
    \bibliographyreadinglist{readinglist}
    \bibliographystyleresources{plain}
    \bibliographyresources{resources}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:
[image]

Since my reading list and resources are both short, I want to put them on the same page. Also, I want to keep using `report` as my documentclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` around your bibliographies, then `\def\chapter*#1{\section*{#1}}` after `\begingroup`. Like so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{readinglist}{Reading List}
\newcites{resources}{Resources}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \def\chapter*#1{\section*{#1}}
    \bibliographystylereadinglist{plain}
    \bibliographyreadinglist{readinglist}
    \bibliographystyleresources{plain}
    \bibliographyresources{resources}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

The code `\def\chapter*#1{\section*{#1}}` redefines the chapter command to a section command. Bibliographies tend to use the chapter command for their headers, but now it will use the section command instead, which does not force a new page :)